# On Liouville numbers and the Continuum Hypothesis

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, transcendental-numbers

Collecting some theorems from the book *[Making Transcendence Transparent](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387214445)* by its authors, there is some inconsistency, I think... :

**i.** $L= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 10^{-n!}$ is transcendental.

**ii.** Numbers of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n 10^{-n!}$ in which $a_i \in {\{0,1}\}$ are Liouville 
numbers and thus transcendental. So, by Cantor diagonalization argument there are uncountably many Liouville numbers.

**iii.** The collection of all Liouville 
numbers has measure zero. The set of all sequences of zeros and ones (not all zero) are in 1-1 correspondence with $(0,2)$ and this is in 1-1 correspondence with $\mathbb{R}$.

How an uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has measure zero?

Comment: Which inconsistency do you see (" there is some inconsistency, I think").

Comment: There is no inconsistency in an uncountable set of measure $0$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I had never seen an uncountable set of measure $0$ that's why I am confused.

Comment: Well, you've seen one now.

Comment: Incidentally, I disagree with the downvote (and have upvoted) - this is a perfectly reasonable confusion to have at first, and what is MSE for if not dealing with perfectly reasonable confusions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the Cantor subset of $\mathbb{R}$: it is compact, uncountable, with no isolated points yet it has measure zero.

Comment: You beat me to it.  It is probably the easiest to understand example of an uncountable set of measure zero.